# How to fail a expectComplete() event and throw error?

Tags: project-reactor

The following is my unit test code. I want to test a condition that an infinite event is generated and event completion should not be expected. I am trying to fail the expectComplete().

```
@Test
    public void testInfiniteEventGeneration() {
        Flux<Integer> flux = serv.myEvent();  // This method generates an infinite event.

    assertThatExceptionOfType(AssertionError.class)
    .isThrownBy(() -> StepVerifier.create(flux).
            expectNextCount(1).expectNextCount(2).expectNextCount(3)
                           .expectComplete()
```

// eventComplete should fail as the event is generated inifintely.

```
  .verify())
    .withMessageEndingWith("Event should be infinite.");

}
```

Need help to achieve it. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test that some `Publisher` is infinite, in theory, you should wait an infinite duration and check that it does not complete. Of course, you can't do that in a test suite.

Depending on your use case and what behavior you're like to check, you could:

- use [the virtual time feature](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#_manipulating_time) to manipulate time and check that your `Publisher` is sending a lot of values for a sensible duration
- if no event is supposed to be published, `expectNoEvent(Duration)` can check that
- in all cases, you'll need to chain your expectations with a `thenCancel()` to cancel the subscription and end the test